# My global node app don't find .env or localstorage file in the project folder

Tags: node.js

I have created a little node app based on dotenv and node-localstorage. My app is supposed to be global.

When I try to launch it from the module folder, there is no problem. All files are found and all is ok.
When I try to launch it from outside the module folder, my app complains that it don't found any files related to those modules.

Should I configure something in the package.json file to fix this problem?

Comment: Note: File paths are relative to the *current working directory* ([`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_cwd)). You'll need to provide an absolute path if you cannot guarantee the working directory used when starting your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, dotenv uses the path `.env` to access your environment file ([source](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path)). This path will therefore be relative to where you are starting your application. For instance if your current working directory is `/somedir` and you run your application using `node /path/to/your/app.js`, dotenv will look for a `/somedir/.env` file, which likely doesn't exist.

To correct this, you can use:

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: '/path/to/your/project/.env'});
```

Comment: I receive { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: '.env' }. And I want to launch my app with just a name like grunt-cli do. So I have put the bin property in my package.json file.

Comment: How are you using your .env file? (from node script, grunt task) When referring to it, are you using `./.env` (with the trailing `./`)?

Comment: I use the dotenv package to save important keys. I don't do anything its the package which load it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Try 
`require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});`
in your main script (should be at the same directory level as your .env). The default path dotenv uses is *.env*, which I suspect causes the problem. I will update my answer if this solves the issue

Comment: I  have this error now: { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/musicli/lib/.env']
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/musicli/lib/.env' }

Comment: Try /your/project/path instead of __dirname, then?

Comment: I have corrected path and now all is ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped. I updated my original answer with this solution